# OUTLOOK VSTO: delete an email after sending it

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm working with vsto for outlook. Create an email message and send it to recipient. 
I want to delete the e-mail from "sent items" (or prevent its entrance there) but can not find a way to do it.
During my attempts I tried to filter emails in "sent items" by "find" and "restrict" functions on the "recipient" but I got an error of "Condition is not valid" or "Cannot parse condition. Error at "...."".

My Code is:

```
     MailItem reportEmail = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);

     reportEmail.Subject = subject;
     reportEmail.To = TeamEmailAlias;
     reportEmail.Send();
```

How can I delete the mail from "Sent Items" now ?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set up the [DeleteAfterSubmit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868585(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class which allows to set a Boolean value that is True if a copy of the mail message is not saved upon being sent, and False if a copy is saved.

```
 MailItem reportEmail = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
 reportEmail.DeleteAfterSubmit = true;
 reportEmail.Subject = subject;
 reportEmail.To = TeamEmailAlias;
 reportEmail.Send();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `MailItem.Delete()` method, which should delete it from whatever folder it is in. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863343.aspx) article on MSDN explains it, and also offers extra resources. You can also delete all items in a folder by using `FolderName.Item(n).Delete()`.